# Set audio thumbnail from a file path and a drawableID in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, audio, thumbnails

recently I am working on a Audio Manger project but don't know how to figure out setting audio thumbnail in android.
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello @bovietvidai, Hope you are doing well. Here I am adding my suggestion to your question.**

### Option 1:

You can create a `bitmap` by using the below code snippet.

```java
Bitmap image = ThumbnailUtils.createAudioThumbnail(file, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
```

in the above code snippet `file` object is the audio file.

---

### Option 2:

You can fetch using a `MediaMetadataRetriever` by using the below code snippet.

```java
MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
byte[] imgbyte;
Bitmap bitmp;
BitmapFactory.Options option =new BitmapFactory.Options();
    
mmr.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri);
imgbyte = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();
    

if (imgbyte != null) 
    bitmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgbyte, 0,imgbyte.length, option);
```

---

### Option 3:

You can fetch using a `Cursor` by using the below code snippet if you are fetching media items using `Cursor`.

```java
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
    new String[] {MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART}, 
    MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID+ "=?", 
    new String[] {String.valueOf(albumId)}, 
    null);
    
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    String albumart = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART)); 
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(albumart);
}
```

I think all 3 options are working well for you.

Comment: the code you provided me is just for fetching image, meanwhile I want to set audio thumbnail not get it

Answer (score 0):

Best Option is to add using glide as it will not create issue of background task and can set some default image if any error

```
val projection = arrayOf(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA
        )

        val query = contentResolver.query(collection, projection, null, null, null)
        query?.use { cursor ->
            // Cache column indices.
            val idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID)
            val nameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)
            val durationColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION)
            val sizeColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE)
            val dataColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA)

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                // Get values of columns for a given video.
                val id = cursor.getLong(idColumn)
                val name = cursor.getString(nameColumn)
                val duration = cursor.getInt(durationColumn)
                val size = cursor.getInt(sizeColumn)
                val data = cursor.getString(dataColumn)


                 val contentUri: Uri = Uri.fromFile(File(data))
                //every device works with this Uri
                val sArt = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart")
                val musicThumbnail: Uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    sArt,
                    id
                )
Glide.with(context).load(musicThumbnail).error(R.drawable.baseline_music_note_24).into(yourImageView)
```